# How to check QUOTED_IDENTIFIER value inside of a script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'd like to check the value of `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` inside of a script I am running.

The script gets put together in a different process and I can't control other parts of it - just mine.  So I want to be able to change it to my preferred value, then reset it to whatever it was before my portion was run.

I tried `SELECT * FROM master.dbo.spt_values sv WHERE sv.name = 'quoted_identifier'`, but it doesn't seem to reflect the current state.  I tried checking `@@QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`, but it doesn't exist in my version of SQL Server.  I tried to query `sys.sysconfigures`, but the information isn't there either.

Is it possible to check the current state of `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`?

Comment: _"but it doesn't exist in my version of SQL Server."_ - what version and edition are you using? what client are you using? Is this in SSMS (if so, you can configure SSMS's `SET` options separately).

Comment: `if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print 'quoted_identifier is on' else print 'quoted_identifier is off';`  (see: comment from  on "Friday, March 31, 2017 5:11 PM" https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/16f24391-60db-456c-9a37-cfc22ee7e707/how-to-find-if-quotedidentifier-is-on-or-off?forum=transactsql